# How to reindex pandas Series by removing nulls between different indices?

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a pandas Series that goes by 5 in indexes like the image;

[image: A Pandas dataframe with indexes incrementing by 5]

I want to transform this Pandas Series to;

0. 20.883339
1. 20.883386
2. 20.883434

...

3652 21.053699

Can I transform my Pandas series like that without creating a new series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resetting the index with `drop=True` will replace it with the default 0-indexed integer index:

```
y_pred = y_pred.reset_index(drop=True)
```